# ftp Загрузка PDF файла на сервер

Tags: c#, wpf, файлы, ftp, fileupload

Нужно загрузить pdf файлы на сервер по ftp. Код :

```
    string username = "myserwer@forfile.sg";
    string Pass = "qwerty";
    string URLpath= "http://ftp.adress.co.uk/";
    string filePath;
        try
        {
            filePath = FullPath.Text;
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, Pass);
                client.BaseAddress = URLpath;
                client.UploadFile(WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, filePath);
           }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox(ex.Message, ex.Source);
        }
```

Вылетает ошибка :

> Базовое соединение закрыто : Соединение было неожиданно закрыто.

Как исправить?

Comment: Скорее всего должно быть `string URLpath= "ftp://ftp.adress.co.uk/";` а не `string URLpath= "http://ftp.adress.co.uk/";`

Comment: @koshe спасибо. заработало!

Comment: @koshe но возникла другая проблема. загруженный файл автоматически называется STOR. и больше одно загрузить не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, Pass);
    client.UploadFile(ftpFileName,WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, filePath);
}
```

где `ftpFileName` полное имя файла на фтп, а `filePath` полное имя локального файла и если у  Вас много файлов нужно загружать, запустите в цикле.

Comment: Спасибо. Уже разобрался, но все равно плюсую!